# Font-awesome icons not working

Tags: html, css, icons

<s>I don't know why whenever i use an icon from https://fontawesome.com and integrate it into my html my browser( google chrome) shows a flashing question mark in place of the icon. Any solutions?</s>

## Update:

The flashing icon issue has been solved, but there's a new issue.

I don't know why whenever i use an icon from https://fontawesome.com it doesn't show at all in my browser. Here's the code i used in my markup.

```
<i class="fab fa-mizuni"></i>
```

And also the script i'm using to call it from my system

```
<script src="Assets/svg-with-js/js/fontawesome.js"></script>
```

but it works when i use a cdn.

Any help?

Comment: check if you are doing things correctly

Comment: Is the location of the style correct? can you atleast post code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flashing question mark means you're not using the appropriate selector or the font isn't loaded appropriately. Note that there is now a prefix difference between different icons, it's not all `fa` anymore.

Read about the new prefixes [here](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/upgrading-from-4#icon-name-changes).

Check out this CodePen: https://codepen.io/xhynk/pen/VXezaX

It shows the old `fa` prefix (flashing ?/!) and the new and appropriate `fab` (FontAwesome **B**rand) prefix.

If you're updating from an old 4.x version of FontAwesome, read the Upgrade Doc here: https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/upgrading-from-4

According to the update in your Question, `Assets/svg-with-js/js/fontawesome.js` doesn't exist, and your path needs to be changed (possibly just adding a `/` before `Assets`). However, I **strongly** urge you to use the default FontAwesome CDN (`https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/all.js`) - rarely is there a great reason to package it in yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If you are simply copy and pasting the icons from the site, that is not enough. Make sure you actually add their javascript to your site, and use the HTML tags. Check the network tab in the Google Chrome developer tools, and verify that it is actually loading the fontawesome js/css.